# Matlab. Difference between plot and fplot?

Tags: matlab, plot

Why use 'fplot' to plot functions when we can use 'plot'? I can't understand

Answer (score 6):

With [**`plot`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) you have to manually define the `x` values and compute the corresponding `y` given by the function.

```
>> x = 0:.01:1;
>> y = sin(10*x);
>> plot(x,y,'.-')
```

[image]

With [**`fplot`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) you define the function *generically*, for example as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html); pass a [handle](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) to that function; and let Matlab choose the `x` values and compute the `y` values. As an example, take a difficult function:

```
>> f = @(x) sin(1/x);
```

Assume we want to plot that between `0.01` and `1`:

```
>> lims = [.01 1];
>> fplot(f, lims, '.-')
```

See how Matlab does a pretty good job choosing closer `x` values in the left area, where the function becomes wilder.

[image]

Comment: Oops. I see now that my `fplot` example is almost the same as in Matlab's documentation